# Expanding nested brackets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In comparison with the other questions on the front page, this seems utterly trivial, and I'm almost embarrassed to ask it! But anyway...

I'm trying to improve my maths by using a couple of recommended textbooks.  One (Basic Maths for the Physical Sciences) has the following question:

*Expand the following for $z$ by removing all the brackets*

$$
   z = [2xy - (x+y)^2]^2
   $$

The first line of the (semi-worked) given answer is

$$
z = 4x^2y^2 - 4xy(x+y)^2 + (x+y)^4
$$

It took me ages to work out how they got this, before realising they were treating the the $(x+y)^2$ has a single entity.  But, I tried to approach it by dealing with the nested bracket first (which I thought *should* be the correct way!), and then expanding, to get

$$
(2xy - (x^2 + 2xy + y^2))(2xy - (x^2 + 2xy + y^2))
$$
$$
(2xy - x^2 - 2xy - y^2)(2xy - x^2 - 2xy - y^2)
$$

but this removes all $xy$ terms, whereas the correct answer is

$$
x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4
$$

What step have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just didn't take you answer far enough. The result of your last step was
$$
(2xy - x^2 - 2xy - y^2)(2xy - x^2 - 2xy - y^2)
$$
Noting that $2xy-2xy=0$ we have
$$(-x^2-y^2)(-x^2-y^2) = ((-1)(x^2+y^2))((-1)(x^2+y^2))$$
$$=(-1)(-1)(x^2+y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2$$
$$=x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4$$

Comment: Yes - I've *just* realised I wasn't expanding the last brackets correctly; I've never seen the $(-1)(-1)$ notation before - this seems to make it a lot easier to expand brackets than $(-x^2-y^2)(-x^2-y^2)$ which is what I had!

Answer (score 3):

All the xy terms canceling, meaning that 2xy and -2xy disappear.  So, we have

(-x$^2$-y$^2$)(-x$^2$-y$^2$).

Expanding we have

(--x$^4$--y$^2$x$^2$--x$^2$y$^2$--y$^4$).

Which in turn yields

x$^4$+2x$^2$y$^2$+y$^4$.

Answer (score 1):

You could firt notice that $$2xy - (x+y)^2=-(x^2+y^2)$$ so $$z=(x^2 +y^2)^2$$ If you take the long way you chose, you arrive, after expansion, to $$z=x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4=(x^2 +y^2)^2$$ I suppose that the goal was effectively to remove all $xy$ terms.

Comment: Hmm, but in the 2nd line of my expansion I've got $2xy - 2xy$ in each bracket, but I should end up (as you say) with $2x^2y^2$ - it's this that I'm confused about

Comment: In each bracket :$2xy-2xy=0$

Comment: Oh, oops, I didn't expand the last set of brackets correctly(!)

Comment: Aaaaah ! Glad that you found it. But, again, you made your life much more difficult than required. Cheers :)